# How to serialize to JSON under Jenkins?

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, xstream

I would like to be able to serialize objects directly to JSON from groovy scripts executed by Jenkins.  I am not very familiar with XStream but it appears that some jettison classes are absent from the XStream build that is bundled with the jenkins core.

From the script console:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver
import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration

new JettisonMappedXmlDriver()
```

Which fails on the last import:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
    Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration
     @ line 3, column 1.
       import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration;
```

Is it possible to get this working with core jenkins or would additional classes need to be introduced via a plugin?  Is there an alternative to XStream that should be considered?

Comment: What are you trying to serialise? Could you just use JsonBuilder?